# Redirect all URL calls to a particular php file

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Any http request (e.g. to pdf) should be redirected to **validate.php** so if you call an URL (e.g. `http:...../whatever/whatever/1.pdf`), **htaccess** should execute **validate.php** instead.

I went through many examples on web and stackoveflow, no luck yet. Since most work fine for many people, I guess there must be something wrong with my server.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

**Note:** htaccess and validate.php files are stored in the root.

- [.htaccess - How to redirect all urls to url.php except index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609413/htaccess-how-to-redirect-all-urls-to-url-php-except-index-php)
- [htaccess Redirect All Requests to Index.php Script](http://www.slashnode.com/php-2/htaccess-redirect-all-requests-to-index-php-script/)
- [How to redirect all requests to a file, except images using
  Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060932/how-to-redirect-all-requests-to-a-file-except-images-using-apache)
- [Redirect All Requests To Index.php Using .htaccess](http://jrgns.net/redirect_request_to_index/)

And many more.

Comment: When the answer to your question is the first question that you have linked, I'd like to tell you that searching is not enough. You also need to read what is written in the results.

Comment: @feeela - How do you know I didn't read! Take that -1 please. Do you think I would risk my server without reading and just doing copy+paste.

Comment: @anubhava, watch your typos, man :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.pdf$ /validate.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: What URL did you use to test this? Make sure this is your first rule.

Comment: That should work. Make sure this is first URL. Also can you post your .htaccess in your question?

Comment: There wasn't a `htaccess` file before! I just created one based on your and others' answers.

Comment: Is .htaccess enabled on your server?

Comment: God bless you my friend. It wasn't and I'm not htaccess nor server admin guy. Enabled it and works perfectly fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your .htaccess file, inside < IfModule mod_rewrite.c > section

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ validate.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are mixing up Apache `.htaccess` redirects and authorization with your desired application level behavior.  At least that is what I am assuming here based on the fact you want every request for a `.pdf` to go through a script called `validate.php` prior to accessing the `.pdf`.

When I say you are mixing things up, the logic to force validation like that should be in your `validate.php` or within the larger framework of your PHP application. That script should validate the user then—after setting a cookie or a session variable or whatever validation scheme you might have—the `.pdf` file is downloaded.

Which is all to say, this is not a simple question to answer in the way you describe.

Comment: You're right. System was developed long time ago without any documentation and in a mess so everyone can access files without login in the system by just typing name of the file. That's my problem. I cannot rewrite whole system.

Answer (score 0):

That's all:

```
# Turn On RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
# Set RewriteBase 
RewriteBase /
# Redirect any http request to validate.php
RewriteRule . /validate.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ validate.php [L]
```

What about this?

Comment: No, still able to see the pdf file. Didn't redirect!